# Pyramid ImportError: No module named registry

Tags: python, pyramid, uwsgi

I have recently upgraded pyramid to 1.5.1 from 1.2 on my machine, when try to start the uwsgi server, now i am getting this error.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 271, in loadobj
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 450, in get_context
    global_additions=global_additions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 559, in _pipeline_app_context
    APP, pipeline[-1], global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
    section)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.7.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 646, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
  File "./xyz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pyramid.authorization import ACLAuthorizationPolicy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/authorization.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyramid.security import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/security.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_registry
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/threadlocal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyramid.registry import global_registry
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/registry.py", line 5, in <module>
    from zope.interface.registry import Components
ImportError: No module named registry
```

How do i proceed to solve this error, I am using uwsgi to run server.I looked for solutions in the similar questions, but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade your `zope.interface` version too. You'll need to install version 3.8.0 or newer.

Other minimal requirements have also updated since 1.2:

- `WebOb` must be 1.3.1 or newer
- `repoze.lru` must be 0.4 or up
- `zope.deprecation` 3.5.0 or newer is required
- `venusian` must now be version 1.0a3 at least
- `translationstring` must be `0.4` or newer.

Take into account that each of these packages may have other dependencies too.

If you are using a buildout, make sure you have a `[versions]` section and pin newer versions. If you have a virtualenv, you should investigate if `bin/pip -U` will get you the correct versions.

However, I'd not make the jump straight from 1.2 to 1.5.1 in just one step. Follow the [upgrade advice](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/upgrading.html), read the change log and see if you can upgrade your application one version at a time; from 1.2 to 1.3.4 to 1.4.5 to 1.5.1 in controlled steps.